# Node.js wait for fs.mkdir() to finish before continuing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, mkdir

I'm working in Node.js and need to create a new directory. I'm using fs.mkdir() for this.

Howvever, I need this directory to be created or at least check whether the creation was successful or not before moving forward with the next bit of code. How could I get a promise or return value from mkdir() that indicates the success or failure of the code before continuing?

Current code:

```
    fs.mkdir('./newdirectory', function(err) {
      if (err) {
          console.log("Error Creating Directory: " + err);
       } else{
          console.log("Success Creating Directory")
       }
     })

  //need code here to execute after knowing whether the directory was successfully created or not
  //currently, this code here executes before the 'console.log()' above would
```

Comment: just use `mkdirSync`

Comment: @ChristianFritz I don't think I'm following along. I can't get either to return anything whether it was successful or not, I just get 'undefined'

Comment: See https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_options. The function is supposed to return ``undefined`` if all went well. If something went wrong, it wouldn't thrown an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Christian Fritz mentioned, what you're looking for `mkdirSync`. It will return undefined in most cases (see: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_options).

All the error validation you need is wrapping it in a `try-catch` block. It will throw an exception if something goes wrong.